# How to Call function from another function

Tags: python-3.x, oop

I tried to call a function in the other function but it is returning an error.

```
class Data_Wrangling:
  def __init__(self):
    self.ClassName = type(self).__name__ + '.'
    self.Host = None
    self.App_Id = None
    self.App_Secret = None
    self.PySpace = None
  
  def Data_Retrieve(self,URL):
    
      print('\n<> ' + inspect.currentframe().f_code.co_name)
      
      JsonData = None
      ST = time.time()
      while JsonData is None:
          try:
              Response = requests.get(URL)
          except Exception as E:
              print('\n>> Failed: ' + str(E))
              if (time.time() - ST)/60 > 1:
                  print('\n>> Failed: NO valid JsonData Retrieved - Source Down or Internet Issue, etc')
                  break
              JsonData = None
              continue

          if Response.status_code == 200:
              try:
                  JsonData = json.loads(Response.content.decode('utf-8'))
              except Exception as E:
                  print('\n>> Failed: ' + str(E))
                  JsonData = None
                  continue
      KN.TPE(ST)
      return JsonData

  def Processing(self, DatasetId):
      Start_Date = '1900-01'
      today = datetime.today()
      End_Range = str(today.year)+ '-' + str(today.month)

      Limit = 5000
      Page = 1

      URL_Part1 = 'https://maps.clb.org.hk/map/pageList?keyword=&startDate='
      URL_Part2 = '&endDate='
      URL_Part3 = '&address=&industry=&parentIndustry=&industryName=&accidentType=&accidentTypeName=&companyOwnership=&companyOwnershipName=&deathsNumber=&deathsNumberName=&injuriesNumber=&injuriesNumberName=&mapType=2&page='
      URL_Part4 = '&limit='

      URL = URL_Part1 + Start_Date + URL_Part2 + End_Range + URL_Part3 + str(Page) + URL_Part4 + str(Limit)

      JsonData = Data_Retrieve(URL)

DW = Data_Wrangling()
Export_FilePath = DW.Processing('dtihwnb')
```

I receive error as:

```
    JsonData = Data_Retrieve(URL)
NameError: name 'Data_Retrieve' is not defined
```

I am stuck here, thinking what is the issue that I have made here. Please help I am calling Data_Retrieve in Processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to call **Data_Retrieve** method using self because its inside the class.

Try to call your method like this..

```
JsonData = self.Data_Retrieve(URL)
```